# Uniform convergence of $C^k$ functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f_n$ be uniformly bounded in $C^k$, and converging uniformly to $f$. Then, it isn't true that $f$ is also $C^k$. But I think $f \in C^{k-1}$. Actually my intuition is that $f$ should be in $C^{k-1,1}$.

How does one prove this?

I'm sure this is standard but I didn't find it and figured I might as well ask it.

Comment: No. The limit is just continuous. Take $f_n(x) = \sqrt{ x^2 + n^{-1}}$.

Comment: Ok thanks I was way off. Can we have $f_n \in C^1$ and the limit not be even Lipschitz? For sure it will be $C^{1-\epsilon}$.

Comment: You should try to compute something. The example daw gave is $C^1$ but the limit is not Lipschitz.

Comment: Afaik the limit of the example that daw gave is $f(x) =|x|$, which is a Lipschitz function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ClaraTorres-Latorre In this case $f$ is Lipschitz, but what if you take $f_n = f$ to be equal to any $C^1$ but not Lipschitz function (for example $\exp$ over $\mathbb{R}$) ?

Comment: Yes that would do it. That makes me realize I actually wanted to ask something different.

Comment: @ClaraTorres-Latorre You can ask another question, then.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I edited the question for it to be the question I wanted to ask (is this even okay to say in a comment?)